# Eclipse kepler create a feature patch

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-kepler

I am trying to reach at the eclipse source code so I can maybe try to modify/fix. I have had more frustrating experiences - very few.

I tried to follow the post by  Ian Bull [Patching your own Eclipse IDE](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/30/patching-your-own-eclipse-ide/)

I switched to the PDE perspective and fired up the wizard New > FeaturePatch. Now I am stuck at:

[image]

So how I populate the browse dialog ? I want to edit formating of java code by the JDT core. Ideally I would like to be able to edit the master branch of the kepler maintenance release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press `Browse` and then type part of the feature id you want to patch. Just typing `j` should show you the jdt feature among a few others.

Comment: Lol - another intuitive UI by eclipse(TM). Do you have any idea how could I plug the code from the git repositories in (I guess this should add the code from my existing eclipse install) ? Is it possible ?

Comment: No I never really looked at patching the code like this. It is unusual to need to do this.

Comment: OK - I will try to do it this way - I am interested in trying my hand in bugfixes (...) but I guess I have a long way to go - so I thought of feature patch to start looking into the code

Answer (score 0):

I found the feature patch to be largely useless (surely due to my own ignorance), and took what wound up to be the easier route:

1. [download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and install Eclipse for RCP and RAP developers
2. import > Plugin-in Development > Plug-ins and fragments
3. check Directory radio button and browse to filesystem directory containing plugin sources
4. under "Import As" check "Projects with source folders"
5. in following screen browse add target plugin(s) you want to modify/work on

Now you'll have the plugin source in your workspace, completely powerless against your devious ways.

Once you've made your changes and have everything working to your liking, backup your standard eclipse install's plugin X and overwrite with version of plugin X from eclipse rcp, which you do with:

```
export > Plugin-in Development > Deployable plug-ins and fragments > Directory [browse..]
```

Comment: Thanks - will have alook ASAP - do I need to download the RCP ? I have JavaEE set up with 69 plugins. Also - how do I import the latest repository code in that ?

Comment: yes, download RCP. Once installed you should be able to import JEE plugins from the filesystem and then have at it, the source is with you ;-)

Comment: Could it be installed as a separate plugin in my existing install ?

Comment: Not sure, I have a lean and mean standard install (platform binary + jdt) so prefer to keep the heft elsewhere